# How can I hook into and edit the text of a wp_nav_menu <a> tag?

Tags: php, menus, filters, hooks

I'm trying to change the text displayed for the anchor tags in the `wp_nav_menu` li's.

I actually managed to do this with jQuery, nothing fancy, because I am certainly no professional. You can see the basic code here:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {

    jQuery('.menu-item-30 > a').html('<i class="fas fa-home"></i>');

});
```

It works, this code will find the anchor tag in the desired nav menu li and change the icon to a tiny little house for the home page. The problem is that when I load the page, for the briefest second, before the house loads I can see the original text in that anchor tag which is "home" and it looks unprofessional. What I am trying to say, is that the page loads and then this code noticeably runs after.

Therefore, I figured this is maybe where filters and hooks come into play. However, from what I understand, you can't really wrap jQuery in PHP and set it as a filter, right? Maybe I just need to change "ready" in jQuery to something else.

Therefore, how can I change the text in between `<a>` and `</a>` from 'Home' to `<i class="fas fa-home"></i>` while at the same time, having it load while the page loads and not after?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One way to achieve such effect would be to use `wp_nav_menu_objects` hook.

```
function modify_home_in_nav_menu_objects( $items, $args ) {
    foreach ( $items as $k => $object ) {
        // you can also target given page using this if:
        // if ( 'page' == $object->object && 2 == $object->object_id ) {
        if ( 30 == $object->ID ) {
            $object->title = '<i class="fas fa-home"></i>';
        }
    }
    return $items;
}
add_filter( 'wp_nav_menu_objects', 'modify_home_in_nav_menu_objects', 10, 2 );
```

PS. Should it really be `fas` and not `fa` in there?

Comment: Thank you, that solved my issue and I will be sure to examine your code and figure out how it works the way it does.

As for the font awesome code, that's just what I copied from the official site but I have heard it changes slightly from version to version.

Comment: @Ruke ahh, maybe you’re right :)

Comment: yes and it's not the page's `id`, but an `id` of a menu item, you will find it by devtools inspector either on site or in the menus admin